# How to match and remove an object from javascript array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to delete an element based on string match for a object property but when I do a slice on the javascript array the array size decreases and indexes change. Please help e with a solution. Here is a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/27o53527/2/) for the same.

Code

```
var selection = JSON.parse('[{"Connectors":"c1"},{"Connectors":"c2"},{"Schedules":"s1"},{"Schedules":"s2"},{"Gauges":"g1"},{"Gauges":"g2"},{"Gauges":"g3"}]');

removeitem("Gauges");

function removeitem(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        if (selection[i].hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            selection.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want the indices to change, you should call `delete selection[i]` instead of `selection.splice(i, 1);`.

Comment: @Loolooii: it will make it `undefined`. Will that not cause a problem?

Comment: @abi1964 depends on what he wants to do. He obviously does not want the size and indices to change, so I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

Add `i--;`

```
function removeitem(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        if (selection[i].hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            selection.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/abhisheksimion/27o53527/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a problem with having `undefined` as the new value, then you could call `delete[i];` instead of `selection.splice(i, 1);` in that case the length does not change and neither will the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Both `Abhi1964` and `Loolooii` solution seems to work fine and solve problem, but i would personally keep the filtered results in separate array instead of manipulating index/deleting value in the same array, reason being, separate array would make code look simpler to read and understand. Reviewer need not to understand the index manipulation or keep track of `undefined`.

```
var selection = JSON.parse('[{"Connectors":"c1"},{"Connectors":"c2"},{"Schedules":"s1"},{"Schedules":"s2"},{"Gauges":"g1"},{"Gauges":"g2"},{"Gauges":"g3"}]');

removeitem("Gauges");
var filteredResult = [];
function removeitem(item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
        if (selection[i].hasOwnProperty(item)) {

        }else{
           filteredResult.push(item);
        }
    }
}   

//use filtered result as per your need.
```

**Note:**
I have not run this code, if some error seems to be there, please feel free to edit.